# credentials for google knowledge graph

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-knowledge-graph

I am trying to use the Google Knowledge graph API. I already have the API key and also use the library instead of the RESTful API.

```
kgSearch = Kgsearch::KgsearchService.new
response = kgSearch.search_entities(query: query)
```

I have tried to instantiate the service as below

```
kgSearch = Kgsearch::KgsearchService.new(api: 'klfkdlfkdlm')
```

it's rejected because the init expect no arguments.

Any idea, how to add the api_key ??

I try also:

```
response = kgSearch.search_entities(query: query, api: 'fjfkjfl')
```

same things

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ruby Docs for the Google Api Client, `key` is an instance method where you can assign your api key (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/KgsearchV1/KgsearchService#key-instance_method).

So I believe you'd do something like the following:

```
kgSearch = Kgsearch::KgsearchService.new
kgSearch.key = 'your_key_here'
response = kgSearch.search_entities(query: query) # and any other options that are necessary
```